# Is there a way to include two versions of the same artifact in Maven?

Tags: maven, jmock

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>   
</dependency>
<!--Include Both Jmock 1&2 is cool: http://www.jmock.org/upgrade1to2.html -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

This doesnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the dependency mediation section in  http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html . One version will win.

Comment: So doesnt look like I can include both :-(

Comment: @DD: no, you certainly can't.